# Java Election Program with JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am coding a little election Program for the upcoming Election's in Germany. Well, it is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String _Kandidat1;
    String _Kandidat2;

    _Kandidat1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you Vote for the AFD or for the CDU ?");
    if (_Kandidat1 == "AFD")
        System.out.println("The AFD won the election!");
    else
        System.out.println("The CDU won the election!");
    }
}
```

If I type in "AFD" it says the CDU won. If I type in "CDU" in nothing happens.
I'm not sure, but I think the mistake is in `if (_Kandidat1 == "AFD")`

Any solutions?

Comment: use `.equals()` method

Answer (score 4):

You need to use equals, otherwise you compare the reference:

```
_Kandidat1.equals("AFD")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read documentation of java for `String` class first. This class is not a primitive type hence equality should not be checked with `==`. You should check the string equality with `.equals()` method.

```
if (_Kandidat1.equals("AFD"))
    System.out.println("The AFD won the election!");
else
    System.out.println("The CDU won the election!");
}
```